# BitmapFactory.decodeFile() returning null when i try to get image

Tags: android, bitmapfactory

```
 String imageInSD = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/DCIM/Soovy/2089.jpg";         
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageInSD);

 if(bitmap == null){                  
     Log.v("combine image", "null");
 }else{ 
     Log.v("combine image", "not null");                  
 }
```

Update: used Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() thanks for the info

Comment: so you got it working?

Comment: Try:`String imageInSD = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "DCIM/Soovy/2089.jpg";`

Comment: yes got is working and as akashasia mention should use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't access the SD card directly, try accessing it through `Environment`.

Like this:

```
String imageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/DCIM/Soovy/2089.jpg";

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageDir);

if(bitmap == null){                  
     Log.v("combine image", "null");
 }else{ 
     Log.v("combine image", "not null");                  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String imageInSD = "file:///mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Soovy/2089.jpg";
```

You should however not hardcode paths. Use

```
Environment.getExternalStorageState()
```

to get the root of sdcard.

```
String imageInSD = Environment.getExternalStorageState() + "/DCIM/Soovy/2089.jpg";
```